# xamarin forms: the page becomes extremely large and I am not sure why

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <ScrollView>
    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="0">

        <Label FontSize="Large" Margin="6" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Text="Revisión Técnica" HorizontalOptions="Center"></Label>
        <BoxView HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HeightRequest="3" Color="Black"></BoxView>

            <StackLayout IsVisible="True" Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="0" x:Name="ContainerSec" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <StackLayout Padding="0" Spacing="0">
                    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="LightGray" Padding="0">
                        <Label Margin="8" VerticalOptions="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" Text="Lista de detalles"></Label>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout Padding="0" Spacing="0" x:Name="VisualColumnWRP" WidthRequest="{Binding widthCol,Source={x:Reference Pagexaml}}" MinimumWidthRequest="{Binding widthCol,Source={x:Reference Pagexaml}}">

                    </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>

                <BoxView WidthRequest="3" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Color="{StaticResource type2-color}"></BoxView>

                <StackLayout Padding="0" Spacing="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start">
                    <Grid x:Name="ElGrid" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="0"/>
                         <RowDefinition x:Name="row1" Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition x:Name="row2" Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition x:Name="row3" Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition x:Name="row4" Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition x:Name="row5" Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition x:Name="row6" Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="0"/>

                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />

                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalOptions="End" Margin="5" Text="Garantía"></Label>
                    <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" HorizontalOptions="Start" Margin="5" x:Name="Garantia"></Label>
                    <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalOptions="End" Margin="5" Text="Descripción"></Label>
                    <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" HorizontalOptions="Start" Margin="5" x:Name="Description"></Label>
                    <Label Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalOptions="End" Margin="5" Text="Detalle"></Label>
                    <Label Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" HorizontalOptions="Start" Margin="5" x:Name="Detail"></Label>

                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="5">
                        <Label Margin="5" Text="Estado"></Label>
                        <suave:MaterialPicker x:Name="Picker" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="5"></suave:MaterialPicker>
                    </StackLayout>

                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="5">
                        <Label Margin="5" Text="Nota"></Label>
                        <Editor x:Name="EditorWRP" HeightRequest="100" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"></Editor>
                    </StackLayout>

                    <StackLayout Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="5">
                        <suave:MaterialButton Clicked="MaterialButton_Clicked"  BackgroundColor="LightGray" Text="Agregar evidencia" Margin="5"></suave:MaterialButton>
                    </StackLayout>

                </Grid>
            </StackLayout>


        </StackLayout>
            <Image x:Name="GalleryImage"></Image>
    </StackLayout>

    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

the previous code generate the next screen but is height is a lot bigger than the height of the tablet emulator and I don't know why.

[image: screen of the app]
The only way that I solved it was declaring the grid with fix height, but even when the window is big and I checked its height value, turns out to be small. Thank you for your help

Comment: Can you tell me which emulator you are using??

Comment: I use the xamarin android device manager, the emulator use the api 27 and the device is a 7" WSVGA

Comment: You are using tab there for you are able to see the UI like this. You can choose and select mobile emulator it will work properly.

Comment: I already solved it, i wouldn't recommend it but I tried different things and that work. My soultion was to evaluate the size when the phone changed orientation and when the data was updated, and at least use it too when the boxview change. I installed the app in my phone and it looks bad too, but now it looks fine!

Answer (score 0):

You can put your scroll view into absolute layout and set bounds and flags - it should work